# Ubuntu- How do I change clock speed from terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, cpu, cpu-frequency

What command or program do I need to run in order to change the clock speed to a specific value I want? For example, I'm looking for something like `<command name> 1.7`, or something similar, to change the speed to a specified frequency in GHz or MHz. I would prefer a terminal application, but a desktop app would also suffice.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done with the `cpufreq-set` command from `cpufrequtils`. Here is an example:

```
cpufreq-set -f 1700
```

Comment: Also `cpupower frequency-info` `cpupower frequency-set -u -u 1200000`. But this does **not** guarantee that temp will go down. For my old core 2 duo CPU setting max speed from 2GHz to 1.2GHz doesn't show any measurable change in power consumption (checked on power outlet).

Comment: ```
root@unit1:~# cpufreq-set -f 1700
root@unit2:~# grep "cpu MHz" /proc/cpuinfo
cpu MHz  : 2113.574
cpu MHz  : 2648.479
cpu MHz  : 2232.932
cpu MHz  : 2355.421
cpu MHz  : 2689.360
cpu MHz  : 2112.556
cpu MHz  : 2113.505
cpu MHz  : 2113.348
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, you have to use this on a multicore CPU: for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7; do cpufreq-set --cpu $i -f 1700; done

Comment: Thank you for your solution! However, I think there is an extra `-u` in `cpupower frequency-set -u -u 1200000`.